# how to open Runner.xcworkspace in xcode

Tags: flutter, xcode, cocoapods

Tell me, I choose Runner.xcworkspace -> open in xcode in the Android studio, but for some reason runner.xcodeproj opens. How to open a workspace?

[image: my files]

Xcode - xcode-beta-8

Comment: Right click on the ios folder in the android studio, then choose flutter->open in xcode. Thats way you can open the ios version code in xcode.

Comment: @KKMuhammedFazil I can open it, but you see, I have the Runner.xcodeproj file open, not Runner.xcworkspace

Comment: do you fixed this issue ?

Comment: @KKMuhammedFazil No, unfortunately I still have this problem

Comment: why u need to open runner.xcworkspace. runner.xcodeproj is the main file and u only need this push configure the builds.

Comment: @KKMuhammedFazil The solution to my main problem is to open runner.xcworkspace, not runner.xcodeproj